# DC coupled output question

Tags: dc

I want to control an analogue synthesizer with CV from my audio interface outputs. i have tested with a multimeter and the output seems to be DC coupled with this i mean that when i send a DC offset it remains steady there are no capacitors at the output to filter the DC offset. Also the output after some tests seems to work allright. But i ask here to further understand. How to identify if my output can carry DC signals without geting damaged? is this a specification of the interface or this can be tested electrically?

Comment: Just putting a multimeter across an outout does not tell you it's DC coupled.  The input impedance of the meter is in 10's of Mega Ohms.  Terminate with a resistor first. e.g. 10k.

Comment: @Jason Morgan Thanks. can you please elaborate what you mean by terminate with a resistor? connect a 10k resistor from ground to the positive signal?